# Python - for-loop, replace letter in a string

Tags: python

I've written a function that replaces all instances of 'X', but how do i make it so that it only replaces it in the interval from start to stop?

```
def replaceSegment(string, replace, start, stop):
    newstring = ''
    for x in string:
        if x == 'X':
            newstring = newstring + replace
        else:
            newstring = newstring + x
    return newstring
```

> Write a function, replaceSegment, which takes a string, str, and another
>   string, replace, and two integers, start and stop. The function should return a
>   new string in which all occurrences of the substring "X" in the original string,
>   str, in the range from index start to but not including index stop, is
>   replaced with the replace string.
>
> Built-in functions or modules that perform the same or similar tasks,
>   not be used in this task. However, it is permissible to use the len() function.
>
> example:
>
> ```
> ReplaceSegment >>> ("HXej! BalXoo X", "hope", 3, 7)
> 'HXej! Hope balXoo! ')
> ```

Comment: For future reference, if you actually want a function that does this rather than wanting to make one, then there is `str.replace`.

Comment: If this is an assignment (it looks like one) please first try to do it by yourself..

Comment: The easy solution is to do string concatenation: `first_part + replace_stuff(segment) + last_part`.

Comment: The sample output doesn't match the function description. There is *no* `X` in `inputstring[3:7]`, case changes unexpectedly (`hope` becomes `Hope`, `Bal` becomes `bal`, and the last `X` is dropped altogether).

Answer (score 0):

Think of `start` and `stop` as dividing the string into three parts:

- The first part starts at the start of the string and ends just before `start`,
- The second starts at `start` and ends just before `stop`,
- The third starts at `stop` and goes until the end of the string.

So, only the second part gets changed.

If you can succesfully isolate those three parts, you can start `newstring` off as just the first part, apply your loop only to the second part, and then add the last part on at the end. It looks like this:

```
def replaceSegment(string, replace, start, stop):
    # before  = the part of string before start
    # segment = the part of string from start to before stop
    # after = the part of the string from stop to the end of string
    newstring = before
    for x in segment:
        if x == 'X':
            newstring = newstring + replace
        else:
            newstring = newstring + x

    newstring += after
    return newstring
```